# How to import lodash library in js file

Tags: javascript, lodash

```js
import { shuffle } from 'lodash';
```

```html
    <script type="module" src="./script.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/lodash@4.17.21/lodash.js" ></script>
```

How to solve this issue? the library is not loading and getting multiple errors such as
*Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "lodash". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".*
or can't import outside the module. How to fix it? My HTML head is above, I got the CDN from their website and I only need to import shuffle.

Comment: Have you tried to set the lodash script first?

Comment: If you are doing this from the browser, you shouldn't need to import it.

Comment: I did try putting my lodash script first no luck. and when I don't import it, it doesn't recognize it when I use it in my script

Comment: You're looking for `import { shuffle } from 'lodash-es'` (lodash exported as es modules).

Comment: This gives me the same error unfortunately

Comment: Have you tried installing `lodash-es` first? `npm i lodash-es` or `yarn add lodash-es`? You can only `import` installed packages  in `node`.

Comment: I am on vs code, how do i do that?

Comment: you run any of those commands in terminal

Comment: it says command not found